# Laravel Eloquent hasManyThrough Relationship, SELECT without

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, has-many-through

I have 3 entities:

Company, User, Ticket

I need to select ALL companies that have no tickets, how can I manage that using Eloquent?

this are the relationships

```
class Company extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'companies';

    protected $fillable = array('name', 'priority', 'shortname', 'color');

    public function users() {

        return $this->hasMany('User', 'companies_id');

    }


    public function tickets() {

        return $this->hasManyThrough('Ticket', 'User', 'companies_id', 'from_users_id');

    }

}

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';    

    public function company() {

        return $this->belongsTo('Company', 'companies_id');

    }

    public function tickets() {

        return $this->hasMany('Ticket', 'from_users_id');

    }

}

class Ticket extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'tickets';

    public function user() {

        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'from_users_id');

    }    

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not documented but `Company::doesntHave('tickets')` should work.

http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_doesntHave

Comment: this kind of thing should be on the main page :p